# Unable to start apache, error SSLCertificateFile takes one argument, SSL Server Certificate file (`/path/to/file' - PEM or DER encoded)

Tags: apache, aem, dispatcher

I have setup the dispatcher in Apache for windows OS. After that trying to configure certificates to enable HTTPS in httpd.config file, then getting below exception every time. Not sure what's wrong here. Using apache 2.2.25 and generated key using openssl.

Any help on this problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please use quotes for the file path:

```
SSLCertificateFile "<path-to-file>"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "<path-to-file>"
```

The path you are using contains multiple "spaces" which probably are interpreted as another parameter.

Comment: Thanks Jens. It's working now after providing double quote

Comment: @SnehaAgarwal That is great. Please accept this answer so that others can immediately see, that this is the solution. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry for the reply on an old post, I am facing the exact same issue with same error but however my path-to-file are wrapped in quotes but it's still not working. Any pointers?